# How do you change the attribute text color in Swift 3.0 with CPPTextStyle

Tags: macos, core-plot

I have tried all I can think of to change the attribute color from the default black. I can display an annotation in black but when I try to change the default color, what seems to work with UIFonts doesn't work with CGFonts on the Mac. Any suggestions. The code below displays YAxis in black but then I cannot change the default font color.

```
    let annY = CPTLayerAnnotation.init(anchorLayer: hostingView.hostedGraph!.plotAreaFrame!)

    annY.rectAnchor = CPTRectAnchor.left; //to make it the top centre of the plotFrame
    annY.displacement = CGPoint(x: 20.0, y: 0.0) //To move it down, below the title

    let textLayerY = CPTTextLayer.init(text: "Y Axis")

    annY.contentLayer = textLayerY

    hostingView.hostedGraph?.plotAreaFrame?.addAnnotation(annY)

    let textAttributes = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: CGColor.white,
        NSStrokeColorAttributeName: CGColor.white,
        NSFontAttributeName: ("HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", 12)] as [String : Any]

   /* let textAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: CGColor.white,
        NSStrokeColorAttributeName: CGColor.white] as [String : Any]*/

    var theTextStyle :CPTTextStyle

    theTextStyle.textStyleWithAttribute(CPTTextStyle.color: CGColor.white)

    let ann = CPTLayerAnnotation.init(anchorLayer: hostingView.hostedGraph!.plotAreaFrame!)

    ann.rectAnchor = CPTRectAnchor.bottom; //to make it the top centre of the plotFrame
    ann.displacement = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 20.0) //To move it down, below the title

    let textLayer = CPTTextLayer.init(text: "X Axis", style: theTextStyle)

    ann.contentLayer = textLayer

    hostingView.hostedGraph?.plotAreaFrame?.addAnnotation(ann)
```

Comment: Use `NSColor`, `NSFont`, etc. on the Mac instead of `UIColor`, `UIFont`, etc. from iOS.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my question is more how do I pass the NSColor into the CPTText layer?

Comment: Figured it out. You have to first define a CPTMutableTextStyle. Then populate the color with a CPTColor other than black. Finally, you instantiate a CPTTextLayer with text: and style. Hope this helps others.

Comment: ` let textStyle :CPTMutableTextStyle = CPTMutableTextStyle()
        
        textStyle.color =  CPTColor.white()

        let ann = CPTLayerAnnotation.init(anchorLayer: hostingView.hostedGraph!.plotAreaFrame!)
    
        ann.rectAnchor = CPTRectAnchor.bottom; 
        ann.displacement = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 20.0)
        
        let textLayer = CPTTextLayer.init(text: "X Axis", style: textStyle)
        
        ann.contentLayer = textLayer
        
        hostingView.hostedGraph?.plotAreaFrame?.addAnnotation(ann)`